# Select Rows from a Table where a connected table has more than X entries

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following Tables:

```
posts
post_id | user_id | text
1       | 12      | blabla
2       | 64      | sususus
```

and

```
comments
comment_id | post_id | user_id | text
1          | 1       | 55      | I like this...
2          | 2       | 66      | Yeah, me also!
...
```

Now posts and comments are connected by the post_id id. How can I get all posts that have less than 18 comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS total 
    FROM comments 
    GROUP BY post_id
    ) p2 
ON p.post_id = p2.post_id 
WHERE p2.total < 18 OR p2.total IS NULL
```

Here you're using a subquery to get all the `post_id`s and the number of comments for each post. You then connect this to the posts table using `LEFT JOIN` so your results include posts which have no comments.